# Python - вывод значений с print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
print(0 or "" or 124 or "test2" or True)
```

Выводит - 124.

Почему?

Comment: видимо потому, что 0 и пустая строка дают false.... а 124 уже true. ну собсн оно и возвращает как только попалось

Comment: Был ещё подобный код но в конце с False и он выводил 0, почему так?

Comment: Да у меня нет кода, это в универе в тесте было, спросить у самого лектора пока не вышло, ибо пара только во вторник, а пока так по памяти пытаюсь

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze, подозреваю, что в том коде было `and`, а не `or`.

Comment: Да, вспомнил. Было and, как тогда это работает с and ?

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле `print(False or 0)` выведет 0. Да и просто `print(False)` выведет False

Comment: Да но почему при and он выводит 0 ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я имел в виду `print(0 and "" and 124 and "test2" and False)`

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze, последнее значение, на котором точно становится известно значение выражения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Операция `or` возвращает *первый операнд с логическим значением `True`*.
(Когда такого нету, так *последний*).

(Это *слишком необычное* так как многие языки программирования возвращают всегда только `True` или `False` - или что-то подобное, как `1` или `0`.)

Так как *не нулевые числа* (и *не пустые строки / списки* и т. д.) имеют значение `True`, вы получаете как результат `124` - первый операнд с логическим значением `True`.

(См. [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) и [Boolean Operations - and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).)

Comment: почему тогда `print(False or 0)` выведет 0? Да и просто `print(False)` выведет False

Comment: Вы правилен - для [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) результат `x or y` есть `y`, когда `x` `False`, иначе `x`. - Отношение вашего второго примера с моим ответом не понял. - Спасибо вам - я сейчас поправлю мой ответ.

Comment: `Отношение вашего второго примера с моим ответом не понял` - ну просто глядя на предложение "Операция or возвращает первый операнд с логическим значением True." можно было предположить, что 0 дает False (и уж тем более сам False) и поэтому не попадает в output и тогда становилось непонятным  почему  по этой логике не работает `print(False or 0)`.... Вот сейчас чуть прояснилось